# He never asked anything from me. (from vs. of)

Tags: prepositions

> He never asked anything from me.

'ask' takes 'of' before personal pronouns like 'Can I ask a favor of you?'

Can I replace 'from' in the sentence above with 'of'?

> He never asked anything **of** me

Comment: idiom: to ask something of someone

Comment: @Lambie You think the example sentence should be rewritten with 'of' (instead of from)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct and natural, and mean the same thing.

According to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=asked%20anything%20of%20me%2Casked%20anything%20from%20me&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), the version with "of" is more than 5x more common.